# Centering DIVS & Footer issue

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with my DIVS and my footer, essentially what I want is three divs that are spread apart have an icon above them, a title and a brief sentence or two below it, here,

http://prntscr.com/evcxo6

, you see if I'm adding information to my page it making it scroll and the footer isn't at the bottom of the page. I can't seem to get the DIVS centered and allow them so if the screen size starts to get smaller I want them to collapse into a column. If anyone could help with my small issues i would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

HTML

```html
<section id="boxes">
    <div>
    <div class="box">
    <img src="ico/clock.png">
    <h3>Time</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ante sem varius consequat commodo libero morbi curabitur, 
    enim maecenas imperdiet etiam per ut semper tempor himenaeos, non fringilla 
    congue vivamus aptent cubilia aliquam mattis.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
    <img src="ico/settings.png">
    <h3>Work</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ante sem varius consequat commodo libero morbi curabitur, 
    enim maecenas imperdiet etiam per ut semper tempor himenaeos, non fringilla 
    congue vivamus aptent cubilia aliquam mattis.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box">
    <img src="ico/recycle.png">
    <h3>Recycle</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ante sem varius consequat commodo libero morbi curabitur, 
    enim maecenas imperdiet etiam per ut semper tempor himenaeos, non fringilla 
    congue vivamus aptent cubilia aliquam mattis.</p>
    </div>

    </section>

    <footer>
 <p>Mandurah Jetty Maintenance | Copyright &copy 2017</p>
    </footer>
```

CSS

```
#boxes {
  margin-top: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#boxes .box {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#boxes .box img {
  width: 90px;
}

footer{
  padding: 20px, 0px, 0px, 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: you want to center the divs in the middle of the page?

Comment: With regards to your footer, you're probably looking for `position: fixed` rather than `position: absolute`. Or perhaps you're looking for a [Sticky Footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/). As for your 'stacking' of columns, you'll need media queries that provide a `width` attribute. You may want to look into a framework like Bootstrap, Foundation, Skeletal or Toast to help with that.

Comment: @repzero Yea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position the footer fixed to the window, i.e., `position:fixed`

Add an id to the div container that holds all other div name `box_container`

Apply a display flex property in box_container

Add media queries so that when the window resizes to fit mobile, the flex-drection of `box_container` changes to `column`. I add only one mobile media query. you can add more

Add  a `margin-bottom` to the body tag. why? remember you positioned the footer fixed? it might block contents

[click here for demo](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/xdKBKN?editors=1100)